# Keras model.predict for multinomial logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, data-science

I'm training a model whose output is a softmax layer of size 19. When I try `model.predict(x)`, for each input, I get what appears to be a probability distribution across the 19 classes. I tried `model.predict_classes`, and got a numpy array of the size of `x`, with each output equal to 0. How can I get one hot vectors for the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a documentation of [`predcit_classes`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) is somehow misleading because if you check carefully its [implementation](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/8f7574437951a8f1042407d25bffb57292e3b6a6/keras/models.py), you'll find out that it works only for binary classification. In order to solve your problem you may use the `numpy` library (basically - a function [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)) in a following way:

```
import numpy as np
classes = np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis = 1)
```

.. in order to get an array with a class number for each example. In order to get a one-hot vector - you might use a `keras` built-in function [`to_categorical`](https://keras.io/utils/np_utils/#to_categorical) in a following manner:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
classes_one_hot = to_categorical(np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis = 1))
```